# How to write a letter with two half lines to the right of it?

Tags: equations

How do you draw this in Latex?
[image: How do you draw this in Latex?]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try  `P\textsuperscript{||}`.

Comment: If you're looking for a "math prime", then `$P'$`, `$P''$`.

Comment: This seems to be a math symbol, perhaps `$P^{\parallel}$`

Comment: P^{\parallel} was what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what’s being sought here, but as indicated in the comments, some possibilities would be `P''` or `P^{\parallel}`,¹ both in math mode. (if the P is meant to be upright, it could be set in math mode using `\mathrm{P}` instead of merely `P`.

Bernard's suggestion of `P\textsuperscript{||}` will not necessarily work. In particular, in pdfTeX, with the default fonts, the input `|` will give — thanks to Knuth trying to fit all the characters he needed into a 7-bit encoding and choosing to replace certain characters normally used only in math mode with other text characters (the other notable substitutions being ¿ for `>` and ¡ for `<`.

---

1. This is the most likely “correct” solution assuming that this symbol is used in some geometric context.

Comment: P^{\parallel} was what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
P$^{\,\rotatebox{90}{=}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Strange, but formally OK, until the OP explain what (s)he wants. :-)

Comment: It’s visually *passable* but it’s useless for, e.g., output to html or any possible accessibility.